# Conditionally make field optional based on selected state - Woocommerce(NOT RESOLVED)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

I’ve been trying for a while now to find a solution to this issue I am facing, that being that I desire to condition the `billing_city` field in checkout to be optional while hidden only when the customer selects a certain state from the drop-down menu.

This is the code I’ve used to achieve the conditional hidding/showing, but it doesnt make the field unrequired, thus making it impossible to place an order.

```
  add_action( 'wp_footer', 'conditionally_hidding_billing_city' );

function conditionally_hidding_billing_city() {
            // Only on checkout page
            if ( !is_checkout() )
                return;
            ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(function($){
                // Choosen billing state selectors slug
                //var billingState = '#billing_state',

                // Function that shows or hide input select fields
                var billingState = $('#billing_state').val();

                // Initialising: Hide if chosen billing_state is "BS"
                if( billingState == 'BS1' || billingState == 'BS2' || billingState == 'BS3' || billingState == 'BS4' || billingState == 'BS5' || billingState == 'BS6'  )
                    showHide('hide','#billing_city' );

                // Live event (When billing state is changed)
            $( '#billing_state' ).on( 'change', function() {
                var billingState = $('#billing_state').val();
                if( billingState == 'BS1' || billingState == 'BS2' || billingState == 'BS3' || billingState == 'BS4' || billingState == 'BS5' || billingState == 'BS6' )
                {
                    showHide('hide','#billing_city');
                    $('label[for="billing_city"]').hide();
                }
                else{
                    showHide('show','#billing_city');
                    $('label[for="billing_city"]').show();
                }
            });

                        function showHide( actionToDo='show', selector='' ){

                    if( actionToDo == 'show' )
                        $(selector).show( 200, function(){
                            $(this).addClass("validate-required");
                        });
                    else
                        $(selector).hide( 200, function(){
                            $(this).removeClass("validate-required");
                        });
                    $(selector).removeClass("woocommerce-validated");
                    $(selector).removeClass("woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field");
                }

            });


        </script>
    <?php
}
```

As far as I was able to understand, this code only removes the class, but doesnt really make it dissapear, which is why it still triggers the required warning.

I would really appreciate a solution as to what exactly would I need to change in order for it to work.

Thanks a lot, waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To Remove 'required'

```
$('#billing_city').removeAttr('required');​​​​​
```

To add 'required'

```
$("#billing_city").prop('required',true);
```

Comment: Hello Colin, thanks a lot for your contribution. I have tried adding it below showHide functions, yet it looks like the frontend is ignoring it. Could you perhaps tell me where to exactly place this? Thanks a lot :D

Comment: ah, I think it might be this that's wrong: function showHide( actionToDo='show', selector='' )

Comment: I think it should be: function showHide( actionToDo, selector )

Comment: the values will be passed in when you are calling the function

Comment: i.e in showHide('hide','#billing_city' );

Comment: Well, I have tried changing the function as you've said, yet it still doesnt make the field optional and i get the same error. I really appreciate your contribution but i guess theres something I'm not aware of that doesnt make this function work properly

Comment: What's the error message? is it showing in your console log i.e from inspecting the page?

Comment: Well, perhaps error wasnt really the right word. I am talking about the frontend warning that shows "City is a required field", even though the field is hidden. In the inspect part, when i test to see the code's behaviour, it shows that the script only gest hidden, but not deleted. Perhaps this si why this issue is so stubborn. Hope i have made myself undersood

Comment: Are you using other scripts to validate the form?

Comment: Could you try adding console.log('showHide'); inside your showHide function perhaps a few of them to see if they show in your console

Comment: No, this is all the code I have used in order to validate it, and the rest is from the default woocommerce code, I guess. I apologize for the long thread, I would've messaged you but I dont have enough reputation :(

Comment: What about using console.log()

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply but I was busy trying to fix this issues. The console.log() doesnt seem to work either. But thanks a lot for your contribution